# JQuery how pick the Monday of the week of the picked day

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datapicker

I use Datepicker JQuery   and I need to select the monday of the weeks of the day that the user picks.
i.e.

The user picks 13th of march 2013(Wednesday).
   so I'd like to pick 11th of march 2013(monday).

I hope I'm clear.
Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this solely in JavaScript. You can get the weekday from a specific given date by using `getWeekDay()`. That also means you can get the difference (in days) between the day from the picked date and monday of that week.

Then you can subtract the difference in days by setting a new timestamp. This means you need to get the milliseconds between the picked day and monday of that week which you can get by multiplying the number of days with 24 (to get it in hours), then with 60 (minutes), another 60 to get the seconds and finally 1000 to get it in milliseconds.

The result would be something like:

```
function getMonday(/** Date */ date) {
    var diff = (date.getDay() == 0 ? 6 : date.getDay() - 1);
    date.setTime(date.getTime() - (diff * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    return date;
}
```

I also wrote a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nL5Qs/) to test it.

Comment: TNX then I used  `$("#date_fiels").change(function(){
  
   var dateMonday = getMonday( $.datepicker.parseDate("dd-mm-yy",  $(this).val()));
   $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate( "dd-mm-yy", dateMonday ));
   });`